# How to play audio podcast file from libsyn rss feed? (drupal)

Tags: drupal, audio, rss, flash, feed

Got an established libsyn rss feed, got a new drupal website for the podcast. Libsyn provides a player but not correct aesthetic. I can upload and play mp3 files with audio module and mp3player module, and like the mp3 player's output, a simple flash player, but I don't want to be manually moving the podcast audio files (mp3) over every week. Looked at importing automatically with Feeds, but it's not working and besides that's creating extra files unnecessarily on the drupal site.

Just want to use the mp3player modulee's flash player in a drupal page, which feeds the latest mp3 file from a libsyn rss feed. Don't really need to store or play multiple episodes, just the latest episode.

How would you do it?

Comment: Are you willing to develop a custom Drupal module to do this?

Comment: I may have to, I created a separate short-term workaround, but this idea is what I really want. 

I'm most disappointed right now that I lost 50 hard earned SO points for this bounty, and they aren't giving the points back despite ZERO answers being posted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a content type for my podcasts with a title and a field for the URL of the MP3
2. Use FeedAPI and map the title to the title of the node
3. Map the file URL to the URL field
4. Use Contemplate to set the URL field to display as `[swf file="token_for_URL_field"]`, which will use the SWF Tools module and whatever player I've selected to play the file

So you need these modules CCK, Contemplate, FeedAPI, and SWF Tools, and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have your own site be the master and libsyn get it from you? Do they not allow an import feature, with which you'd keep your existing RSS through them. Then you can have total control over your site and push the content to all kinds of other great podcasting networks.

Realize I may have no idea about libsyn works.

Answer (score -1):

When you say feeds didn't work, how did it fail? Are you using feed mapper? You may need to write a custom plug-in for feed mapper to get it to do the right thing with the video files. Feed api supports expiring imported feed items so you should be able to get it to automatically delete old ones. I'm not sure whether the video files will be automatically deleted when the nodes are. If not, you should be able to make this happen by implementing nodeapi's delete op for the content type you are using to store your imported rss items.

Alternatively, maybe you could just harvest the video's url on libsyn, and have the player use that. I don't know whether there's a good player which supports using a field's data for the location of the source it should play.

Also, if you haven't already, I'd encourage you to post your question on groups.drupal.org since that's read by lots of drupal experts.